# Do you say "travel across" or "travel around"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

In the context of a European travel, which form is more suitable?

1. I have been traveling across Europe
2. I have been traveling around Europe

Comment: They mean different things and so neither is more suitable in general than the other.

Comment: Depends.  Are you traveling across or traveling around.  (Hint: Look up the words in a dictionary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would depend on the intended meaning.

1) Would be correct if the person has been travelling in European countries and more than one country, the connotation is that the travel has been extensive (i.e. they have travelled *across* the majority of Europe).

2) Would be more relevent if they haven't in fact travelled 'across' Europe, but maybe visited a few countries in Europe, if used idiomatically. Technically, 'around Europe' actually means they have been travelling in countries that border Europe, but we are being perhaps a bit pedantic with the language here, none the less the statement is somewhat ambiguous.

So in conclusion if the travel has been through a number of countries, and covering a signficant portion of Europe I would opt for 1.

> I have been travelling across Europe.

If the travel has been to one country in Europe or a couple of European countries, I would opt for a different version, like so:

> I have been travelling in Europe.